# How would I write this if else statement as ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

This is kind of a beginners question but how would I write this JavaScript statement as a ternary operator?
Or what would be the cleanest / most optimal way to write this?

```
if ($("#firstName,#lastName, #email, #message").filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }).length > 0) {
   $("label").css(labelAnimation[0]);
 } else {
   $("label").css(labelAnimation[1]);
 }
```

Comment: It's a bit dense... what is that code supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$(
  "#firstName,#lastName,#email,#message").filter(
    function() { 
      return $(this).val(); 
    }
  ).length > 0
)
? $("label").css(labelAnimation[0]) : $("label").css(labelAnimation[1])
```

Or in one line:

```
$("#firstName,#lastName,#email,#message").filter(function() {return $(this).val();}).length > 0) ? $("label").css(labelAnimation[0]) : $("label").css(labelAnimation[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep things somewhat readable, put the boolean result into a variable first. Then put the conditional inside the index lookup brackets:

```
const anyInputsFilled = $("#firstName,#lastName,#email,#message")
    .filter(function () { return $(this).val(); })
    .length > 0;
$("label").css(labelAnimation[anyInputsFilled ? 0 : 1]);
```

I'd suggest extracting the values from `labelAnimation` first though, eg:

```
const [anyFilledCSS, noneFilledCSS] = labelAnimation;
// ...
const anyInputsFilled = $("#firstName,#lastName,#email,#message")
    .filter(function () { return $(this).val(); })
    .length > 0;
$("label").css(anyInputsFilled ? anyFilledCSS : noneFilledCSS]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```js
$("label").css(labelAnimation[
    $("#firstName,#lastName,#email,#message").filter(() => $(this).val())
        .length > 0 
           ? 1
           : 0
])
```